# Using object-hash in an Angular 8 project causes "Cannot read property 'crypto' of undefined" error

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, object-hash

I have an Angular-CLI project which makes use of the [object-hash](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash) library for creating hashes from objects. Normally I would just put

`import * as objectHash from 'object-hash'`

at the top of one of my component files and then do `const hash = objectHash(obj)` anywhere I needed a hash.

I just upgraded my project to *Angular 8* and suddenly, the Angular project *serves* great, but when I run a production build, I get an error: `Cannot read property 'crypto' of undefined`.

This is because Angular 8 generates *differential JavaScript*, generating some bundles for newer browsers as `<script type="module">` and older browsers as `<script nomodule>`. When a script has `type="module"`, apparently `this` is treated differently- so the *object-hash* library's reference to `this` is broken: https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/issues/71

**Does anyone have any insight into how I might resolve this?**

Potential solutions I'm seeing are:

- Importing the *object-hash* library differently somehow
- Using a completely different browser-compatible object-hashing library (I haven't found one yet)
- Getting Angular-CLI v8 to stop generating differential JS and just spit out old-fashioned bundles (I haven't found a solution to this
  one yet)
- Downgrading to Angular 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the commit [1e0835c](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/commit/1e0835cad7d273b521b8a3beee6c7cb8bd778bee), upgrading [object-hash](/questions/tagged/object-hash) to `v2.0.1` should solve the problem (see the [author's comment](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/issues/71#issuecomment-560028463) in the reported issue)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use custom webpack configuration as in the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1548#issuecomment-450891241) you mentioned, because it is a build phase problem, not runtime. As i can see angular core members will not fix this problem soon.

You will get all the features from `angular/cli` build (because `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` is based on default angular builder), but will be able to write your own webpack rules. In my opinion it is very safe additional config:

```
module.exports = {
  node: {
    path: true,
    crypto: true,
    fs: 'empty'
  }
}
```

and i think you will never break something with `@angular` upgrades.
For example on my work project we use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` in more aggressive manner: we replace some plugins and loaders and use ours. And sometimes it just breaks.