# Angular version upgrade 8 to 13 giving error in browser console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'crypto')"

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I upgraded my Angular project from version 8 to 13. after that, I tried to compile the project its compiled successfully and also build successfully.
But when I tried to open the project in the browser its blank screen and the console showed **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'crypto')"**

but I have installed crypto.js also but why still it's giving the error I couldn't able to find it.

Can you please help me to fix this.

This is my console error
[image: This is my console error]

This is my package.json file:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "~0.1303.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.11",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@markpieszak/ng-application-insights": "^7.0.3",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.5.11",
    "@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/object-hash": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "change-case": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^4.0.0",
    "google-maps-ng2": "^1.0.10",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.1.1",
    "node-gyp": "^4.0.0",
    "object-hash": "^1.3.1",
    "oidc-client": "1.11.5",
    "pikaday": "^1.8.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "python": "0.0.4",
    "replace-in-file": "^5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.3.3",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.7-rc.0",
    "select2-bootstrap4-theme": "^1.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.3.11",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.36.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/pikaday": "^1.7.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.4",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "typescript-tslint-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete crypto.js package and reinstalled it?

Comment: Yeah @Reaper, I have tried reinstalled and modified the versions also but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the fix for this issue.

Source link - [Using object-hash in an Angular 8 project causes "Cannot read property 'crypto' of undefined" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57393092/using-object-hash-in-an-angular-8-project-causes-cannot-read-property-crypto)

Thanks to [lealceldeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640649/lealceldeiro)

I upgraded the object-hash.js version to v2.0.1 it got fixed.

Comment: Since the solution is from another SO post - this question can be marked as a duplicate :)